# Android application which should get installed only on phone and not on tablets

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I've built an app but due to layout issues in tablets i decided not to make the application available to them.
I've put in manifest as.

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="7" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="11"        
    android:maxSdkVersion="12"/>

    <supports-screens android:resizeable="false"
            android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="false" android:anyDensity="false" />
```

but still application can be installed on tablets..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use   **compatible-screens**  as described here for specific installations...

[More Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Comment: sorry hanry... i still dont get it
ive put compatible screen tag in my manifest. i used it so that it would be compatible wid small and normal screen. BUT market shows GalaxyTab 10.1 as compatible with my application..im worried about that thing only...Thanks

Comment: Look in document for:
**Caution:** If you use the <supports-screens> element for the reverse scenario (when your app is not compatible with larger screens) and set the larger screen size attributes to "false",then external services such as Android Market do not apply filtering. **Your application will still be available to larger screens,but when it runs,it will not resize to fit the screen.** Instead,the system will emulate a handset screen size (about 320dp x 480dp). If you want to prevent your application from being downloaded on larger screens, use <compatible-screens>.

Comment: Is there any way to test how these configurations will work for Play Store listing?

Answer (score 2):

I have meet the same problem, don't require any  tag. just use it, it will work like charm.

```
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Set your `maxSdkVersion="10"` and target also as `"10"`

Comment: But what about Samsung Galaxy Tab with Android SDK 2.2? And yes Shash, do you also not want in Samsung Galaxy Tab with 2.2?

Comment: yes..then he can detect in his coding that its a tab or a handset and make the app visible only on handset..What do you think about this paresh??

Comment: my issue is not with api level but with screen size.
although  my first thought was to eliminate all the 3.0 tablets.
but then i came across 2.1 chinese tablets till 2.2 or 2.3 galaxy tabs.
still thanks for your support.

Comment: @kanika
no mam you must not show the application to the user in market if its not compatible with there device...Or else after buying the app they will be complaining about your product.

Comment: @Shash yes shash exactly, you are right, its really not preferrable to check from code because think for the user having tablet and purchased your app, then should we give them message "Sorry you are having tablet and you are not allowed to use this app?"

Comment: this is not related to screen size restrictions

Comment: SDK related to API level but no tablet support relates to Device screen size!